# Consumer<T> that turns checked exceptions into unchecked exceptions reference issue

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I have come up with the following code, to be able to pass by consumers that automagically turn checked exceptions into runtime exceptions.

The idea is that the code inside the consumer *may* throw a checked exception, and if it does so, then it will be converted to a runtime exception.

The interfaces:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface WrappingConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T> {
    @Override
    default void accept(final T t) {
        toRuntimeException(() -> wrappingAccept(t));
    }

    void wrappingAccept(final T t) throws Exception;

    static void toRuntimeException(final ExceptionRunnable exceptionRunnable) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(exceptionRunnable);
        try {
            exceptionRunnable.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface ExceptionRunnable {
    abstract void run() throws Exception;
}
```

The testing class:

```
public class WrappingConsumerProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WrappingConsumer<Integer> wrappingConsumer = WrappingConsumerProject::test; //Works
        Consumer<Integer> consumer = wrappingConsumer;  //Works

        testConsume(wrappingConsumer);  //Works
        testConsume(consumer);  //Works

        testConsume(WrappingConsumerProject::test); //Fails
        testConsume((Consumer<Integer>)WrappingConsumerProject::test);  //Fails
    }

    private static void test(Integer integer) throws IOException { }

    private static void testConsume(Consumer<Integer> consumer) { }
}
```

How can it be that some versions just work, and that others give compilation errors?

I am compiling it on Netbeans 8.0, maybe that is of help.

Comment: You may be interested in [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)

Answer (score 2):

My educated guess:  `testConsume` expects a `Consumer<Integer>` parameter:

```
private static void testConsume(Consumer<Integer> consumer) { }
```

So when the compiler sees this:

```
testConsume(WrappingConsumerProject::test); //Fails
```

it of course can't tell that you want to interpret the method reference as a `WrappingConsumer<Integer>`, and you haven't told the compiler anything that would help it believe this is supposed to be a `WrappingConsumer<Integer>`.  (Obviously looking at the name `WrappingConsumerProject` isn't enough of a hint.  :-)  So it has to try to interpret `WrappingConsumerProject::test` as a `Consumer<Integer>`, which means it's equivalent to

```
testConsume(new Consumer<Integer> () {
    public void accept(Integer t) {
        WrappingConsumerProject.test(t);
    }
}
```

which fails because `IOException` isn't handled.  On the other hand, if it *knew* that the interface was a `WrappingConsumer<Integer>`, it would handle it correctly, because then it would interpret the method interface as part of the implementation of `wrappingAccept()`, rather than `accept()`.  Thus:

```
WrappingConsumer<Integer> wrappingConsumer = WrappingConsumerProject::test;
```

is equivalent to

```
WrappingConsumer<Integer> wrappingConsumer = new WrappingConsumerProject<Integer>() {
    public void wrappingAccept(Integer t) throws Exception {
        WrappingConsumerProject.test(t);
    }
}
```

which is OK since `wrappingAccept()` has a `throws` clause.  When this new object is treated as a `Consumer<Integer>`, it's still OK because when the `accept()` method is called:

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer = wrappingConsumer;

// then somebody calls
consumer.accept();
```

it calls the `default` you set up; it doesn't call `WrappingConsumerProject.test` directly.  That fact was already determined when `wrappingConsumer` was declared.  Casting it to `Consumer<Integer>` doesn't change that fact.

But that's not the case with, say

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer2 = WrappingConsumerProject::test;
```

or

```
testConsume(WrappingConsumerProject::test); //Fails
```

In those cases, it has to assume `WrappingConsumerProject::test` is the implementation of `accept()`, because it has to interpret it as a `Consumer<Integer>`.  Nothing tells it to interpret it as a `WrappingConsumer<Integer>`, as explained above.  Thus if somebody called

```
consumer2.accept();
```

it *would* try to call `WrappingConsumerProject::test` directly, without going through your `default`.

Anyway, although I'm not an expert on the nuances of type inference or other JLS rules, this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding jep in Java 8 is http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101

On my machine does the example work directly from command line without errors.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b129)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.0-b69, mixed mode)
```

With integration in Eclipse Luna it is not compiling. 
So my guess is, that this is a tooling problem right now and will vanish over time.

EDIT: Complete rewrite of answer.

Comment: I'd also be interested in why the first two `testConsume()`'s actually *do* work, similarly for casting. Is it that method references are 'weaker'?

Comment: I do not fully get, what you mean with 'weaker'. 

WrappingConsumer<Integer> wrappingConsumer = WrappingConsumerProject::test; is the same as WrappingConsumer<Integer> wrappingConsumer = (Integer i) -> WrappingConsumerProject.test(i); And the test method fits with the signatuer to the Consumer-interface. So everything is fine. But: I can't compile with Eclipse Juno.

Comment: One more note. Directly on the command line it is compiling and running?!? ... java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b129)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.0-b69, mixed mode) In my case the integration with Eclipse is not yet working. Maybe the same with Netbeans.

Comment: I'm not able to compile it with my javac appereantly, but yours is working? Using the 1.8.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Issue. I'm compiling in Eclipse Kepler. This was my result:

```
    testConsume(wrappingConsumer);  //Works
    testConsume(consumer);  //Works

    testConsume(WrappingConsumerProject::test); //Fails
    testConsume((Consumer<Integer>)WrappingConsumerProject::test);  //Fails
```

However:

```
    testConsume((WrappingConsumer<Integer>)WrappingConsumerProject::test); //Works
```

When it fails for me, it is failing with an `Unhandled Exception type IOException`.  The reason is that your `testConsume` method is expecting a Consumer interface. When you provide the method reference `WrappingConsumerProject::test`, this fulfills the `Consumer<Integer>` contract. The compiler has no idea about the `WrappingConsumer` interface because the expected type is a `Consumer` not a `WrappingConsumer`.

Adding the cast lets the compiler know that the interface it should be using for the method reference is a `WrappingConsumer`, and that interface can handle the Exception.

Comment: However the method reference should, in an ideal world, result in a lambda implementing the `WrappingConsumer<T>` interface (exactly because of the signature), and that is also a `Consumer<T>`. You need to keep in mind that you can define your own functional interfaces, and lambdas/method references will use those.

Comment: @skiwi But how will it know which to use?  It seems to me that if both `WrapperConsumer<T>` and `Consumer<T>` would work for the Lambda, and the method signature specifies a `Consumer<T>`, the lambda would be interpreted as a `Consumer<T>`. That appears to be what is happening in the compiler anyway.

Comment: I'd expect that the actual method reference gets compiled to the appropiate lambda, and then that would be used for finding the applicable method. Do note though that the Java compiler seems to be able to understand it perfectly, it's just the IDE's that fail.

Comment: @skiwi FWIW, my java compiler does not compile this code (Command Line). `(Java version "1.8.0"  \  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)  \  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)`

Comment: I actually tested aswell and mine is neither working, should've verified it myself first.

Comment: @skiwi How would the compiler determine the "appropriate lambda"?  There's nothing there that gives the compiler any clue that it should even look at `WrapperConsumer<T>` to compile the method reference.